# What causes android exception "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Tags: android, android-theme

I am attempting to try out the new Material Theme in Android.

I am currently stuck with this exception

```
03-06 09:35:50.177: D/AndroidRuntime(30607): Shutting down VM
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): Process: com.example.vivz, PID: 30607
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vivz/com.example.vivz.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at com.example.vivz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-06 09:35:50.178: E/AndroidRuntime(30607):    ... 10 more
```

My main activity extends `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`

My res/values/styles.xml resembles this

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

</resources>
```

My res/values-v21/styles.xml resembles this

```
<!-- Activity themes -->
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
</style>
```

My application is running on a Nexus 7 with Android 5.0.2

my manifest file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vivz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I can make my application start by deleting the styles.xml file from my res/values-v21 folder.

I do not understand whats wrong and why removing the reference to the one theme I actually want to use fixes the issue.

What have I missed in my rush to try out Material?

Comment: You have metioned your activity extends `ActionBarActivity` change to `Activity`

Comment: when i try that i get "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Material.Light'."

Comment: Theme.Material don't work with ActionBarActivity. Change your v21 theme to AppCompat too and it will work

Comment: I changed to extend Activity and it works. which is nice, however I still dont get how the you tube video i watched extends from ActionBarActivity and uses Theme.Material.Light for v21 and that works. I f use AppCompat in v21 I am not using Material theme at all?

Comment: @Hector I had the same problem... took me ages to notice i needed to use "android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" instead of "Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" (I'm writing this for future users that will run into the same problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using ActionBarActivity then you need to use the ThemeCompat styles. You can only use Theme.Material if you use "Activity" instead.

You CAN still use API 21 items like tinting and elevation natively, but in order to use the native material theme you must use the Activity class.

You can still use a Material UI style while using the AppCompat libraries, however: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: how does this bloke make it work in this video then? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h57QpXp2TRg.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The styles.xml in the v21 folder should also use Theme.AppCompat.x for ActionBarActivities because the ActionBarActivity class is the base class for all Activities that uses the support library action bar features.

Comment: In the video he isn't running a v21 emulator, so he hasn't hit that exception. If he had done, he would've... and would probably have stopped his video there, haha.

Comment: Just to say, though, if you don't intend on using Material UI on pre Lollipop devices, then you can just extend Activity instead and in the values folder, use "android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" and in the values-v21, use "android:style/Theme.Material.Light". You only need AppCompat if you intend on having Material on older devices.

Comment: I would like to have a consistent use of "Material". Also I still not get why the video i watched worked fine mixing Appcompat and Material and extending from ActionBarActivity

Comment: i must admit i like the idea of having only one res/values folder.

Comment: Like I said, in the video he hasn't compiled and run it in a Lollipop emulator. The second he'd've run an emulator running API 21 it would've force closed and shown the error you got.

Comment: Like I said, in the video he hasn't compiled and run it in a Lollipop emulator. The second he'd've run an emulator running API 21 it would've force closed and shown the error you got. You can still use a second values-v21 folder for some styles to only run on Lollipop. Many of the Lollipop only features like tinting and elevation will still work for those devices only :)

Comment: I have searched for an answer to this exception for a long time.
In my case I did all the right changes - however , I failed to add toolbar .
In themes from appcompat you do not have action bar so you need to declare toolbar and set it as ActionBar.

The error is exactly the same as described above.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to use a feature (from the design library, for example) which was introduced after your target sdk.  Therefore, you need to use a couple of libraries (design and appcompat), one of which is the AppCompat Theme (backwards app compatibility).

In your Manifest file, include in your application declaration

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Rebuild and your problem should be solved.