# Use Theme.Material for API21 and above and maintaining compatibility in an Activity with a Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I want to use the Theme.Material for all the device with API21 and above and maintain compatibility with devices pre API21. I follow the guidelines explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) and created 2 Style.xml.
This one for API21 and above

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/USMABlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/USMABlueDark</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And this one for pre API21 devices

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/USMABlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/USMABlueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/USMAAccent</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

My question is what class my MainActivity should extend. 
To work with pre API21 devices my MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity but with device with API21 and above I understand that I should extends Activity (cf. [What causes android exception "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897340/what-causes-android-exception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-desce))...

Moreover if I extend Activity How do I set my toolbar? I use setSupportActionBar in AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `AppCompatActivity` you can use the same class and the **same style** for all devices:

In `values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/USMABlue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/USMABlueDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/USMAAccent</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
</style>
```

Just add some attrs in `values-v21/styles.xml` (it is not required):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
   <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
   <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I understand that the theme android:Theme.Material (http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) is not widely use for the moment. For compatibility purpose it is better to use AppCompat and AppCompat provides all the features of Theme.Material.

Comment: Yes. AppCompat wraps the the material theme for api<21, and uses the material theme for api21+.