# Why are Google's instructions for Material Design incorrect?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have seen similar questions asked with solutions which solve my problem but I was wondering if anyone can explain it to me.

I am following instructions on the Google Developer website to apply the Material Design Theme located [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/get-started.html). However, I am getting an `IllegalStateException` when I try to run the app on the emulator. My theme inherits from `parent="android:Theme.Material"` as specified in the instructions provided by Google.

The issue is solved by using `Theme.AppCompat`. Why is it that the instructions that Google provide leads to an error? I read that `Theme.AppCompat` extends `Theme.Material`, I don't know if that is true. Why can't Theme.Material cannot be used?

I tried following the line of extension for `Theme.AppCompat` but I didn't see it inherit from `Theme.Material` anywhere.

Comment: Could you please provide stack trace? Or could you please tell me, what parent you use for your Activity?

Comment: If you find the content as misleading and blatantly wrong you must submit a ticket to that website instead. You're asking in a wrong website my friend.

Comment: You have to use `Theme.AppCompat` because of your `minSdkVersion`, which is lower than the one which introduced the `Theme.Material` (API Level 21): See the note on [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin I use AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Enzokie I did say I have solved the problem. I simply want to know if anyone has an explanation why it is like this.

Comment: @BobMalooga I even tried changing the minSdkVersion but that did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that the instructions that Google provide leads to an error?

The instructions assume that you are using `Activity`, not `AppCompatActivity`, as your base class for your activities. In your case, you are using `AppCompatActivity`.

> I read that Theme.AppCompat extends Theme.Material, I don't know if that is true.

<strike>It is not true.</strike>

On Android 5.0+ devices, `Theme.AppCompat` will extend `Theme.Material`, indirectly. On older devices, it will not, as `Theme.Material` did not exist. Your error is coming from `AppCompatActivity`, which validates that you are using a theme that is based on `Theme.AppCompat` and therefore does not accept `Theme.Material`.

Comment: They should've mentioned that to be honest. Changing it definitely got rid of the error. So what is the difference between the two besides Activity being the base class? What is the correct way to apply Material Design  to an app. It seems that you can use Material Design widgets with AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Courtney: "They should've mentioned that to be honest" -- the documentation quality varies. "So what is the difference between the two besides Activity being the base class?" -- `Theme.Material` is native to Android 5.0+ and does not exist on older devices. `appcompat-v7` (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.) are a backport of the action bar and the Material Design aesthetic that works back to API Level 7 (Android 2.1). "What is the correct way to apply Material Design to an app" -- "correct", like beauty, lies in the eye of the beholder. Either approach can work.

Comment: Do you know if you lose any functionality, widgets, or view properties by using the Theme.AppCompat theme and AppCompatActivity activity for Android 5.0+ devices?

Comment: @Courtney: None that I am aware of.

Comment: `Theme.AppCompat` has a parent of `Base.Theme.AppCompat` which has an (indirect) parent of `Platform.AppCompat` which on API 21+ devices is `Theme.Material`, so you **are** using `Theme.Material` on API 21+ devices when you use `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank. You were very helpful.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: That's... twisty. :-) Anyway, I updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have one (or all) of two these problems:

1) You use only 1 xml file style.xml, where your wrote something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material">
```

And then you run app for device with api lower than 21. 
   Then you have problem, that devices with api < 21 don't know about your Material theme.

2) You use Material theme for api>=21 and AppCompat for api < 21, but your Activity extends AppCompatActivity, then you have a problem. Because AppCompatActivity requires AppCompat theme, not material

Please, have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897340/what-causes-android-exception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-desce) for more details 
Also from official documentation [page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) about AppCompatActivity:

> Base class for activities that use the support library action bar features.
>
> You can add an ActionBar to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending this class for your activity and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I understand what they intended to do. I don't understand why they gave us an interface to Theme.Material if they knew it would be an issue. They could've just exposed us the AppCompatActivity with the appcompat library and have it scaffoleded on Material Design if you understand what I mean. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It is a "backward compability". It's a main anchor for all of these changes in api, that seems silly to you, or to me :) It's is a main reason, why in android there are over9000 "support"-duplications of classes.